# Storing web correlated files into another project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, web, web.xml

I'm creating a web project using Spring MVC (with Maven). I would like to create three layers: DAL (myproject.dal), BLL(myproject.bll), PL (myproject.pl) (Presentation Layer). I've created three separated maven projects for all of these. Now I would like to create a main myproject.product WEB project, this will have all the mentioned projects as dependency. 
The problem is that, I would keep all the web correlated files into the myproject.pl project, like web.xml, spring-bean-conf.xml, JSP files, etc.

When I run myproject.product on server it do not get the web.xml file. (All these files and folders are created with the correct structure in the myproject.pl.

So what I would like to do is to store the web.xml and the other web related files out of the web project.

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, it is it possible what I would do ?

Thanks for your help,
Have a nice day, Robert.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say about "Can '3 Spring MVC projects' run in one MVC project ? ".

But i am using 2 different java projects in one MVC project.

I have three layer :

1. MVC
2. Process
3. Business

Create Spring MVC project. This is 1

Create two Maven-Plugin these are 2 and 3.

And add them in pom.xml like dependency.

I wish it's usefull for you.

Comment: I do not want that, because I want to separate all the web correlated files into the PL layer. I've didn't said, but between the PL,BLL,DAL layers and between the PRODUCT layer exists an another layer, named MODEL. The model is used to initialize all the project related settings. (global context, flags etc etc)

Comment: Okey But i am sory about that bcs i dont know how can you do that